# How to integrate/install latest c++ protobuf (3.2) with Android NDK?

Tags: android, c++, compilation, cross-compiling, protobuf-c

The earlier protobuf version 3.0 was easily integrated. But there are issues with the latest version 3.2. It simply compiles & builds all the un-related Android .cc file components as well.
If we follow the path to latest branch in [git for c++ proto](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases) & build it as per the steps, then it generates 15 MB .SO file, unlike earlier which was ~1-2 MB.

How to optimally integrate latest protobuf to Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using cross platform [Android Standalone Tool chain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html) and provided build script may result in larger size of Shared library file(.so), generated due to unwanted files included in build script.You can create your own `Android.mk` file which includes only required core part of the library. Generated library files can be used as pre built library in other Android projects. Please check bellow steps for second option of creating own script files.

1. Download latest Android Google Protobuf source from [Git Source Repository](https://github.com/google/protobuf.git).
2. Create New Android application project. Create directory by name `jni` inside application project.
3. Run following commands from the downloaded source directory.

> ./autogen.sh
>
> ./configure

4. Place downloaded source code inside `jni` directory.
5. Place bellow Android.mk and Application.mk file inside `jni` directory.

**Android.mk**

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    c_includes := $(LOCAL_PATH)
    LOCAL_MODULE := libprotobuf      

    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    google/protobuf/arena.cc \
    google/protobuf/arenastring.cc \
    google/protobuf/extension_set.cc \
    google/protobuf/generated_message_util.cc \
    google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.cc \
    google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream.cc \
    google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc \
    google/protobuf/message_lite.cc \
    google/protobuf/repeated_field.cc \
    google/protobuf/stubs/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.cc \
    google/protobuf/stubs/atomicops_internals_x86_msvc.cc \
    google/protobuf/stubs/bytestream.cc \
    google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc \
    google/protobuf/stubs/int128.cc \
    google/protobuf/stubs/once.cc \
    google/protobuf/stubs/status.cc \
    google/protobuf/stubs/statusor.cc \
    google/protobuf/stubs/stringpiece.cc \
    google/protobuf/stubs/stringprintf.cc \
    google/protobuf/stubs/structurally_valid.cc \
    google/protobuf/stubs/strutil.cc \
    google/protobuf/stubs/time.cc \
    google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc \
    google/protobuf/any.cc \
    google/protobuf/any.pb.cc \
    google/protobuf/api.pb.cc \
    google/protobuf/compiler/importer.cc \
    google/protobuf/compiler/parser.cc \
    google/protobuf/descriptor.cc \
    google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc \
    google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc \
    google/protobuf/duration.pb.cc \
    google/protobuf/dynamic_message.cc \
    google/protobuf/empty.pb.cc \
    google/protobuf/extension_set_heavy.cc \
    google/protobuf/field_mask.pb.cc \
    google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.cc \
    google/protobuf/io/gzip_stream.cc \
    google/protobuf/io/printer.cc \
    google/protobuf/io/strtod.cc \
    google/protobuf/io/tokenizer.cc \
    google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.cc \
    google/protobuf/map_field.cc \
    google/protobuf/message.cc \
    google/protobuf/reflection_ops.cc \
    google/protobuf/service.cc \
    google/protobuf/source_context.pb.cc \
    google/protobuf/struct.pb.cc \
    google/protobuf/stubs/mathlimits.cc \
    google/protobuf/stubs/substitute.cc \
    google/protobuf/text_format.cc \
    google/protobuf/timestamp.pb.cc \
    google/protobuf/type.pb.cc \
    google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/field_comparator.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/field_mask_util.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/internal/datapiece.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/internal/default_value_objectwriter.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/internal/error_listener.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/internal/field_mask_utility.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/internal/json_escaping.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/internal/json_objectwriter.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/internal/json_stream_parser.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/internal/object_writer.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/internal/proto_writer.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/internal/protostream_objectsource.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/internal/protostream_objectwriter.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/internal/type_info.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/internal/type_info_test_helper.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/internal/utility.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/json_util.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/message_differencer.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/time_util.cc \
    google/protobuf/util/type_resolver_util.cc \
    google/protobuf/wire_format.cc \
    google/protobuf/wrappers.pb.cc \
    google/protobuf/compiler/code_generator.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_enum.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_enum_field.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_extension.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_field.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_file.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_generator.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_helpers.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_map_field.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_message.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_message_field.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_primitive_field.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_service.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_string_field.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.pb.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/python/python_generator.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/ruby/ruby_generator.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/subprocess.cc      \
    google/protobuf/compiler/zip_writer.cc      \


    LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_RTTI=1
    LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11
    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES = $(LOCAL_PATH)/android 
    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-        libstdc++/4.8/include
    LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lz
    LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS += -lz
    LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := $(LOCAL_CFLAGS)
    LOCAL_EXPORT_CPPFLAGS := $(LOCAL_CPPFLAGS)
    LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES)


    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Application.mk**

```
APP_STL :=gnustl_shared # gnustl_static
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
APP_ABI := all
LIBCXX_FORCE_REBUILD := true
APP_PLATFORM:=android-9
NDK_DEBUG:=1
```

6. Run `ndk-build` and required .so files will be generated inside `libs` folder of the project directory.

Comment: How can I install protobuf inside my phone through the terminal using adb shell or something like that? My phone has protobuf 3.0.0, but I want to upgrade the version. I just don't know how to build protobuf for Android (Linux system level)

Comment: Hi, CMakeLists.txt is used now instead of Android.mk , so could you please provide some hints on how to do this with cmakelists?