# ndk-build No rule to make target for protobuf

Tags: android, android-ndk, protocol-buffers, ndk-build

I've been trying to use ndk-build to get my protobuf library for Android Development and I keep hitting some snags. I got my Android.mk file from a different stackoverflow thread and it doesn't seem to be working. I'm new to this .mk stuff and have no clue what I'm doing.

I found this on the subject as well: [Android NDK: No rule to make target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243047/android-ndk-no-rule-to-make-target)

In that thread they stated that one of the lines had too many spaces at the end so I combed through my own file and couldn't find the source of my problem. I get the message :

```
make: *** No rule to make target `C:/Users/jkarr/Downloads/protobuf-
master/jni/google/protobuf/arena.cc', needed by 
`C:/Users/jkarr/Downloads/protobuf-master/obj/local/armeabi-
v7a/objs/protobuf/google/protobuf/arena.o'.  Stop.
```

Here is my Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
c_includes := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_MODULE := libprotobuf

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
google/protobuf/arena.cc \
google/protobuf/arenastring.cc \
google/protobuf/extension_set.cc \
google/protobuf/generated_message_util.cc \
google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.cc \
google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream.cc \
google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc \
google/protobuf/message_lite.cc \
google/protobuf/repeated_field.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/atomicops_internals_x86_msvc.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/bytestream.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/int128.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/once.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/status.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/statusor.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/stringpiece.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/stringprintf.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/structurally_valid.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/strutil.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/time.cc \
google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc \
google/protobuf/any.cc \
google/protobuf/any.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/api.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/importer.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/parser.cc \
google/protobuf/descriptor.cc \
google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc \
google/protobuf/duration.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/dynamic_message.cc \
google/protobuf/empty.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/extension_set_heavy.cc \
google/protobuf/field_mask.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.cc \
google/protobuf/io/gzip_stream.cc \
google/protobuf/io/printer.cc \
google/protobuf/io/strtod.cc \
google/protobuf/io/tokenizer.cc \
google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.cc \
google/protobuf/map_field.cc \
google/protobuf/message.cc \
google/protobuf/reflection_ops.cc \
google/protobuf/service.cc \
google/protobuf/source_context.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/struct.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/mathlimits.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/substitute.cc \
google/protobuf/text_format.cc \
google/protobuf/timestamp.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/type.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.cc \
google/protobuf/util/field_comparator.cc \
google/protobuf/util/field_mask_util.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/datapiece.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/default_value_objectwriter.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/error_listener.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/field_mask_utility.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/json_escaping.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/json_objectwriter.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/json_stream_parser.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/object_writer.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/proto_writer.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/protostream_objectsource.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/protostream_objectwriter.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/type_info.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/type_info_test_helper.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/utility.cc \
google/protobuf/util/json_util.cc \
google/protobuf/util/message_differencer.cc \
google/protobuf/util/time_util.cc \
google/protobuf/util/type_resolver_util.cc \
google/protobuf/wire_format.cc \
google/protobuf/wrappers.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/code_generator.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_enum.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_enum_field.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_extension.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_field.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_file.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_generator.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_helpers.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_map_field.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_message.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_message_field.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_primitive_field.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_service.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_string_field.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/python/python_generator.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/ruby/ruby_generator.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/subprocess.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/zip_writer.cc \


LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_RTTI=1
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES = $(LOCAL_PATH)/android
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-        libstdc++/4.8/include
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lz
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS += -lz
LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := $(LOCAL_CFLAGS)
LOCAL_EXPORT_CPPFLAGS := $(LOCAL_CPPFLAGS)
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES)


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Not sure if you need my Application File too, but here it is anyways:

```
APP_STL :=gnustl_shared # gnustl_static
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
LIBCXX_FORCE_REBUILD := true
APP_PLATFORM:=android-19
NDK_DEBUG:=1
```

Edit: As a side question would the Android.mk I have here work to get me protobuf-lite?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why it was giving me that error. I was looking the wrong folder. The fixed code is here:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)\src
```

Now I have an entirely different problem. I am getting the error message:

```
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: protobuf <= common.cc
C:/Users/jkarr/Downloads/protobuf-
3.5.0/jni\src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:52:2: error: #error "No 
suitable threading library available."
#error "No suitable threading library available."
^
make: *** [C:/Users/jkarr/Downloads/protobuf-3.5.0/obj/local/armeabi-
v7a/objs/protobuf/google/protobuf/stubs/common.o] Error 1
```

I have no clue where to start with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you were following this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/43729661/3845809, there are a few things causing issues. The main problem is that this post describes how to build v3.2 and you are trying to build v3.5. If you are okay with using v3.2, then the easiest way to fix this is to checkout the 3.2.x branch in protobuf before Step 2 in the post.

In order to build v3.5 for the NDK there are a few things you need to update in the Android.mk file. Here is the updated Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
c_includes := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_MODULE := libprotobuf

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
google/protobuf/arena.cc \
google/protobuf/arenastring.cc \
google/protobuf/extension_set.cc \
google/protobuf/generated_message_util.cc \
google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.cc \
google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream.cc \
google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc \
google/protobuf/message_lite.cc \
google/protobuf/repeated_field.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/atomicops_internals_x86_msvc.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/bytestream.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/int128.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/once.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/status.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/statusor.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/stringpiece.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/stringprintf.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/structurally_valid.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/strutil.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/time.cc \
google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc \
google/protobuf/any.cc \
google/protobuf/any.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/api.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/importer.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/parser.cc \
google/protobuf/descriptor.cc \
google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc \
google/protobuf/duration.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/dynamic_message.cc \
google/protobuf/empty.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/extension_set_heavy.cc \
google/protobuf/field_mask.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.cc \
google/protobuf/io/gzip_stream.cc \
google/protobuf/io/printer.cc \
google/protobuf/io/strtod.cc \
google/protobuf/io/tokenizer.cc \
google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.cc \
google/protobuf/map_field.cc \
google/protobuf/message.cc \
google/protobuf/reflection_ops.cc \
google/protobuf/service.cc \
google/protobuf/source_context.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/struct.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/mathlimits.cc \
google/protobuf/stubs/substitute.cc \
google/protobuf/text_format.cc \
google/protobuf/timestamp.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/type.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.cc \
google/protobuf/util/field_comparator.cc \
google/protobuf/util/field_mask_util.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/datapiece.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/default_value_objectwriter.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/error_listener.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/field_mask_utility.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/json_escaping.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/json_objectwriter.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/json_stream_parser.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/object_writer.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/proto_writer.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/protostream_objectsource.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/protostream_objectwriter.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/type_info.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/type_info_test_helper.cc \
google/protobuf/util/internal/utility.cc \
google/protobuf/util/json_util.cc \
google/protobuf/util/message_differencer.cc \
google/protobuf/util/time_util.cc \
google/protobuf/util/type_resolver_util.cc \
google/protobuf/wire_format.cc \
google/protobuf/wrappers.pb.cc \
google/protobuf/compiler/code_generator.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_enum.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_enum_field.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_extension.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_field.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_file.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_generator.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_helpers.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_map_field.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_padding_optimizer.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_message.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_message_field.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_primitive_field.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_service.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_string_field.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.pb.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/python/python_generator.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/ruby/ruby_generator.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/subprocess.cc      \
google/protobuf/compiler/zip_writer.cc      \


LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_RTTI=1
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11 -D HAVE_PTHREAD=1 -frtti
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES = $(LOCAL_PATH)/android
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-        libstdc++/4.8/include
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lz -llog
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS += -lz
LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := $(LOCAL_CFLAGS)
LOCAL_EXPORT_CPPFLAGS := $(LOCAL_CPPFLAGS)
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES)


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```