# Compiling C++ gRPC for Android

Tags: c++, makefile, android-ndk, protocol-buffers, grpc

How to compile C++ gRPC code for Android? I have seen several tutorials on how Protobuf itself can be compiled using the Android Native Development Kit, such as in the answer from [Swapnil: How to integrate/install latest c++ protobuf (3.2) with Android NDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458739/how-to-integrate-install-latest-c-protobuf-3-2-with-android-ndk)

Or [Google protobuf and Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773136/google-protobuf-and-android-ndk)

But how to How to compile C++ gRPC code that is using Protobuf as well for Android? Taking into account that there's 20K lines of [gRPC Makefile](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/Makefile).

Comment: gRPC has a CMakeLists.txt. Glancing at it, I see nothing that should prevent it to be used to generate NDK targets,

Comment: Did you eventually make it?

Comment: @David how my question can be a duplicate, if it was asked more than a year ago and this one just a few days ago? Also my question is not only about compiling gRPC, but protobuf as well.

Comment: @Taier Ok I mark this other question as duplicate of yours. And the other question has answers addressing grpc and protobuf compilation as grpc depends on protobuf package : building grpc leads to building protobuf

Answer (score 2):

I do it with [dockcross](https://github.com/dockcross/dockcross/) (which does not do anything fancy, it just sets up the toolchain in a convenient way).

Say for [`android-arm`](https://github.com/dockcross/dockcross/tree/master/android-arm) (but it works for [`android-arm64`](https://github.com/dockcross/dockcross/tree/master/android-arm64), [`android-x86`](https://github.com/dockcross/dockcross/tree/master/android-x86) and [`android-x86_64`](https://github.com/dockcross/dockcross/tree/master/android-x86_64) just the same):

```bash
$ git clone https://github.com/grpc/grpc --recursive
$ cd grpc
$ docker run --rm dockcross/android-arm > ./dockcross-android-arm
$ chmod +x dockcross-android-arm
$ ./dockcross-android-arm cmake -DgRPC_BUILD_CODEGEN=OFF -Bbuild -S.
$ ./dockcross-android-arm cmake --build build
```

It will build all the dependencies in the gRPC submodules. It should work in your project if you add gRPC as a submodule (well, up to some point depending on your transitive dependencies situation, I guess).

This said, I am not a big fan of using git submodules for dependencies with CMake. Instead I like to build the dependencies separately and have my project find them with `find_package`. I explain that in more details [here](https://www.acarg.ch/posts/cmake-deps/), and more importantly I have an example doing exactly that for gRPC [here](https://github.com/acarg/cmake-deps-example-grpc).

Answer (score 0):

I've done it [here](https://github.com/4ntoine/JniBenchmarking/blob/master/rpc/CMakeLists.txt).

In brief: git submodule gRPC C++, add "CMakeLists.txt" file to your project on how to build C++ gRPC (and your code that uses it), add a `externalNativeBuild/cmake` it to your "build.gradle" - voila!